Failed to Launch Selector UI: Google Sign-In with CredentialManager in Android
I'm trying to implement Google Sign-In in my Android app using CredentialManager. However, I'm encountering an issue where the selector UI fails to launch, and I receive the error message: "failed to launch the selector UI. Hint: ensure the context parameter is an Activity-based context."
Here's the relevant code snippet:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.clickme);
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CredentialManager credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context);

            GetGoogleIdOption googleIdOption = new GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
                    .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
                    .setServerClientId("clientID")
                    .build();

            GetCredentialRequest request = new GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
                    .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
                    .build();

            credentialManager.getCredentialAsync(context, request, new CancellationSignal(),
                    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
                    new CredentialManagerCallback<GetCredentialResponse, GetCredentialException>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(GetCredentialResponse getCredentialResponse) {
                            Log.d("onresult", "Happened");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(@NonNull GetCredentialException e) {
                            Log.d("onerror", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
                        }
                    });
        });
    }
}

I’ve verified that the client ID is correct, but I’m still encountering this issue. How can I resolve it and successfully launch the Google Sign-In selector UI? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

 I attempted to implement Google Sign-In using CredentialManager in my Android app in java.However, when I click the associated button, I encounter the following error message: “failed to launch the selector UI. Hint: ensure the context parameter is an Activity-based context.”

I expected the Google Sign-In selector UI to launch successfully, allowing users to sign in with their Google accounts.


The same for me in Jetpack Compose. On Pixel all ok, on Samsung and Xiaomi same exception. Tried application.applicationContext and application.baseContext. CM version 1.2.2 and 1.5.0-alpha05

You have:
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CredentialManager credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context);

The "context" that you're using is the "Application" context and as the error states, it needs an Activity context, so correct that and see if it helps or not. Also, after making that change, you first might want to set setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false) during your initial test to make sure the UI shows up and then change that back to true and then false if you get the No Credential errors.

Thank you. I changed "Context context = getApplicationContext" to "Context context = this".

I changed "Context context = getApplicationContext" to "Context context = this" and now it works.

The solution is to use Activity as a context, at least for CredentialManager.getCredential() call. It is not that simple to achieve in good architecture with clear separation of responsibility, and probably that's why we don't see full solution in docs. Here is my approach with DI using Koin for Compose Multiplatform:

Create interface for authentication. Note, that sign-in method should return instance of other interface to be @Composable. This is needed for the trick of getting Activity context even in multiplatform :

interface GoogleAuth {
    /**
     * Sign-In is possible only from UI, so call getUI().signIn().
     */
    @Composable
    public fun getUI(): GoogleAuthUI

    /**
     * Sign-Out is possible without UI.
     */
    suspend fun signOut()
}


Create interface for the Auth UI. GoogleUser there is a simple dataclass, you can have any for your needs:

/**
 * UI Part of Google Sign-in API.
 * It needs to be provided with UI context (@Composable).
 */
public interface GoogleAuthUI {
    /**
     * Opens Sign In with Google UI, and returns [GoogleUser].
     * if sign-in was successful, otherwise, null.
     * By default all available accounts are listed to choose from.
     */
    public suspend fun signIn(): GoogleUser?
}


On every platform implement these two interfaces. There is no way to escape and have only one interface because of the necessity to get Activity context (see LocalContext.current usage below):

class AndroidGoogleAuth(
    private val credentialManager: CredentialManager,
) : GoogleAuth {
    @Composable
    override fun getUI(): GoogleAuthUI {
        // Get obligatory activity context (application context is not enough for this masterpiece API).
        val activityContext = LocalContext.current
        return AndroidGoogleAuthUI(
            activityContext = activityContext,
            credentialManager = credentialManager,
        )
    }

    override suspend fun signOut() {
        credentialManager.clearCredentialState(ClearCredentialStateRequest())
    }
}


...


internal class AndroidGoogleAuthUI(
    private val activityContext: Context,
    private val credentialManager: CredentialManager,
) : GoogleAuthUI {
    override suspend fun signIn(): GoogleUser? =
        try {
            // Prepare the credential request with Activity context.
            val credentialRequest = getCredentialRequest()
            val credentialResponse = credentialManager.getCredential(activityContext, credentialRequest)
            // Extract Google user from the credential response.
            getGoogleUserFromCredential(credentialResponse)
        } catch (e: GetCredentialException) {
            //
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            //
        }


Finally, setup this in Koin module, something like this. Note, that here you are allowed to pass Application context (and not Actitivity context):

val androidAppModule =
    module {
        ...

        // Firebase Auth and Google API.
        factory<GoogleAuth> { AndroidGoogleAuth(get()) }
        factory<CredentialManager> { CredentialManager.create(androidContext()) }
    }

There is a library KMPAuth that tries to fix this. My solution here was partially inspired with it.
